# Xcode 6 - Prevent swift playground refresh

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

Sometimes I'm writing some code on a playground that takes a while to complete. For example:

```
var values = [[Int]](count: 10000, repeatedValue: [Int](count: 73, repeatedValue: 0))
```

And everytime the playground wants to refresh the results, it has to run that piece of code (that takes a while to run) and it makes Xcode as a whole very sluggish.

I still want to be writing my code on a playground since it has some very nice features for testing your algorithms. However, I'm finding that I have to comment certain lines of code just to continue writing without interruptions.

Is there any way to say to Xcode: "Do not run my playground right now. I'll tell you when it's ready."?

Answer (score 65):

In Xcode 7, you can choose between automatic or manual execution of a playground by clicking and holding the ► arrow at the bottom left part of the playground.[image: screenshot]

[Documentation link](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev188e45167)

Comment: then what's the shortcut for execution?

Comment: @Matian2049 there is no shortcut. You can define it under: Xcode > Preferences > Key Binding >  Execute Playground

Answer (score 5):

I don't know an official way to do this but... If you leave a multiline comment at the bottom of the playground and do not add the closing */ tag it will not run until the closing tag is added.